# asp.net downloading file with french character

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, download

I need to download a file with french file name for example "mé.txt"..I have this code:

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open("filePath", FileMode.Open);
byte[] bytContent = new byte[(int)fileStream.Length];
fileStream.Read(bytContent, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
fileStream.Close();
string fileName = "mé.txt";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytContent);
```

But the problem is that when I have the pop up window to save my file .. Im getting this name : `mÃ©.txt`

How can i fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem has to be solved on the serverside using HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode